# How long does it take to change the status from connecting to open using twilio device connection?

Tags: connection, client, twilio

How long does it take to change the status from connecting to open using twilio device connection?

Since I see inconsistencies in connection and the connection remains in connecting status for a few and does not transition to open state requiring action to manually close the connection and restart again.

Answer (score 0):

Satej, Megan from Twilio here.

There are a number of possible reasons for these inconsistencies. Among them are microphone access, browser settings and versions, or access to your token (i.e. it's expired). But there are also updates coming to version 1.3 of the Twilio.js library that could help isolate these issues.

In the meantime, be sure to put some status callback error handlers in place and include explicit code to disconnect the device and `.disconnectAll()`.

```
  Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
    $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
  });
```

...

```
  Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
    $("#log").text("Call ended");
  });

  function hangup() {
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
  }
```